# How do I filter a specific line from a file output bound a scalar variable?

Tags: regex, perl, vmware

I am trying to use regex to filter out everything but a very specific line of text from a VMware VMX file which I am running through a foreach loop because there are multiples of the file for each VM. Each time the loop runs though it binds the output of [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.50/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm) which is running cat against the file sitting on the VM server to a scalar variable.

I am not sure if that actually made any sense.

Anyhow the problem I am running into is when the script runs it is not matching to anything in my regex expression it is just displaying all of the cated VMX files one after another. I can't figure out what I am missing.

Here is the sample of code of I am working on.

```
sub get_virtual_machines {
my $esx_host = config_file()->{ESX}{host};
my $ssh_port = config_file()->{ESX}{port};
my $esx_user = config_file()->{ESX}{user};
my $esx_password = config_file()->{ESX}{password};
my %options = (
    port => $ssh_port,
    user => $esx_user, 
    password => $esx_password
);
my $ssh1 = Net::OpenSSH->new($esx_host, %options);
print color 'blue';
print "Collecting virtual machine data for $esx_host\n";
my @virtual_machines = $ssh1->capture('vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms');
shift @virtual_machines;
print color 'reset';
# Filter data from ESX\ESXi output
my %virtual_machines = ();

foreach my $vm (@virtual_machines) {

    # Replace "[" with "/"

    $vm =~ s/\[/\//;

    # Replace "]" with "/"

    $vm =~ s/\]/\//;

    # Match ID, NAME and VMX location
    $vm =~  m/^(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\D+)(\D)(\d)(\d)/x;
    # Build hash table of discovered virtual machines
    $virtual_machines{"$2"}{"ID"} = "$1";
    $virtual_machines{"$2"}{"VMX"} = "/vmfs/volumes$3$4";
    $virtual_machines{"$2"}{"Version"} = "$9";
}
undef @virtual_machines;
foreach my $vm (keys %virtual_machines) {
$vm = $ssh1->capture("cat $virtual_machines{$vm}{VMX}");
$vm =~ m/^(\bguestOSAltName\b)/x;
print "$1\n";
}
#print Dumper (\%virtual_machines);
```

}

The part in question is after the "undef @virtual_machines" line. Line 38 in the sample
My first goal is to match the line with the word "guestOSAltName" I think once I get that part done I will be on my way again, just hit a road block.

Here is a sample VMX file to look at too.

```
.encoding = "UTF-8"
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "7"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
nvram = "NS02.nvram"
deploymentPlatform = "windows"
virtualHW.productCompatibility = "hosted"
unity.customColor = "|23C0C0C0"
tools.upgrade.policy = "useGlobal"
powerType.powerOff = "default"
powerType.powerOn = "default"
powerType.suspend = "default"
powerType.reset = "default"

displayName = "NS02"
extendedConfigFile = "NS02.vmxf"

scsi0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0.sharedBus = "none"
scsi0.virtualDev = "lsilogic"
memsize = "512"
scsi0:0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.fileName = "NS02.vmdk"
scsi0:0.deviceType = "scsi-hardDisk"
ide1:0.present = "TRUE"
ide1:0.clientDevice = "FALSE"
ide1:0.deviceType = "cdrom-image"
ide1:0.startConnected = "FALSE"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"
ethernet0.networkName = "solignis.local"
ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
chipset.onlineStandby = "FALSE"
guestOSAltName = "Ubuntu Linux (64-bit)"
guestOS = "ubuntu-64"
uuid.location = "56 4d ab a6 1e 7b c5 43-02 45 7c 24 1f fc 28 d9"
uuid.bios = "56 4d ab a6 1e 7b c5 43-02 45 7c 24 1f fc 28 d9"
vc.uuid = "52 50 c1 4b be 91 07 d5-22 0e 86 ee db 88 6d 8a"
snapshot.action = "keep"
sched.cpu.min = "0"
sched.cpu.units = "mhz"
sched.cpu.shares = "normal"
sched.mem.minsize = "0"
sched.mem.shares = "normal"

sched.scsi0:0.shares = "normal"
bios.forceSetupOnce = "FALSE"
floppy0.present = "FALSE"

ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0c:29:fc:28:d9"
tools.syncTime = "FALSE"
cleanShutdown = "FALSE"
replay.supported = "FALSE"
sched.swap.derivedName = "/vmfs/volumes/4cbcad5b-b51efa39-c3d8-001517585013/NS02/NS02-510988a0.vswp"
scsi0:0.redo = ""
vmotion.checkpointFBSize = "4194304"
pciBridge0.pciSlotNumber = "17"
pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber = "21"
pciBridge5.pciSlotNumber = "22"
pciBridge6.pciSlotNumber = "23"
pciBridge7.pciSlotNumber = "24"
scsi0.pciSlotNumber = "16"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "32"
vmci0.pciSlotNumber = "33"
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset = "0"
vmci0.id = "536619225"
hostCPUID.0 = "0000000a756e65476c65746e49656e69"
hostCPUID.1 = "000006fb000408000000e3bdbfebfbff"
hostCPUID.80000001 = "00000000000000000000000120100800"
guestCPUID.0 = "0000000a756e65476c65746e49656e69"
guestCPUID.1 = "000006fb00010800800022010febfbff"
guestCPUID.80000001 = "00000000000000000000000120100800"
userCPUID.0 = "0000000a756e65476c65746e49656e69"
userCPUID.1 = "000006fb000408000000e3bdbfebfbff"
userCPUID.80000001 = "00000000000000000000000120100800"
evcCompatibilityMode = "FALSE"
ide1:0.fileName = "/usr/lib/vmware/isoimages/linux.iso"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to say with the information you've given, but I think the problem is that the regex

```
$vm =~ m/^(\bguestOSAltName\b)/x;
```

doesn't match the file you've given, because the `^` assertion matches start-of-*string*, not start-of-*line*. Since the regex doesn't match, `$1` keeps its old value from earlier in the program, which gets printed out. For safety, you should check the regex actually matched before using captures:

```
if ($vm =~ m/^(\bguestOSAltName\b)/x) {
    print "$1\n";
}
else {
    carp "Couldn't find guestOSAltName!";
}
```

Or grab the captures by putting the match in list context:

```
# $result gets $1 if the match succeeds, undef if it fails.
my ($result) = $vm =~ m/^(\bguestOSAltName\b)/x
```

To make `^` match start-of-line, you need the `/m` modifier, which changes `^$` to match linewise instead of stringwise:

```
if ($vm =~ m/^(\bguestOSAltName\b)/xm) { ... }
```

This is why Damian Conway in Perl Best Practices recommends that you *always* use `/m` -- because then `^$` *always* do what you intuitively think they should do. [He in fact recommends always using `/xms`. You're one-third of the way there :) ]

---

PS: Everything from this point on is general code-review criticism, not directly related to the question. I hope it's useful, but feel free to ignore it.

I find that overuse of escaped chars in regexes and other double-quotish contexts

```
$vm =~ s/\[/\//;
```

is often better rewritten in a single-quotish context:

```
$vm =~ s'['/';
```

Furthermore, this regex is pretty hard to read:

```
$vm =~  m/^(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\D+)(\D)(\d)(\d)/x;
```

You're using the `/x` tag, why not take advantage of it?

```
$vm =~  m/^(\d+) \s+ # $1: number of some sort
           (\S+) \s+ # $2: identifier we're interested in
           (\S+) \s+ # $3: VMX filename part a
           (\S+) \s+ # $4: VMX filename part b
           (\S+) \s+ # $5: another identifier
           (\D+)(\D) # $6, $7: at least two nondigits
           (\d)   # $8: digit
           (\d)   # $9: version digit
           /x;
```

I'd also consider using named captures:

```
$vm =~  m/^(?:      \d+) \s+ # number of some sort
           (?<ID>   \S+) \s+ # $+{ID}: identifier we're interested in
           (?<VMXa> \S+) \s+ # $+{VMXa}: VMX filename part a
           (?<VMXb> \S+) \s+ # $+{VMXb}: VMX filename part b
           (?:      \S+) \s+
           (?:\D+)(?:\D)     # at least two nondigits
           (?:\d)            # one digit
           (?<VERSION> \d)   # $+{VERSION}: version digit
           /x;
```

Now instead of cryptic references to `$2` and `$9` afterward, you have clear, obvious, self-documenting references to `$+{ID}` and `$+{VERSION}`. I've made the rest of the groups into non-capturing groups `(?:regex)`, but if I want to capture one at a later date I can make it into a named capture without changing the indices of all the other captures, unlike with positional capturing.

Named captures are also less likely to suffer from the old value problem mentioned above, where a failed capture leaves all the `$1` variables in their old state.

Comment: @Solignis start with everything above the line break (before "PS...") then. The rest is just extra advice, not directly related.

Comment: Absolutely perfect I am now moving forward again, just wish I could figure out how to get over one small annoyance. I am sure I will figure it out in time, thanks for the help.

Comment: I like the advice after the line break it makes the regex easier to understand.

Comment: MASSIVE props to you, I tried using a variation of you if statements above, and it solved about 5 problems I could not figure out how to get around.

Answer (score 1):

If I guess right at what you want, it's probably something like

```
if( $vm =~ /^guestOSAltName = (.+)\n/ )
{
  print "$1\n";
}
```

Comment: Not really, what I am looking to do is read the entire output from Net::OpenSSH and print the line "guestOSAltName" and its value after the equals sign.

Comment: You forgot the curly braces... :)

Comment: @Solignis mghicks' solution looks about right to me - it looks for the line starting with 'guestOSAltName' and captures whatever comes after the equals sign. It only does the printing when the line in question has been read (unless I'm missing something obvious here...). In what way is this not what you're looking for?

Comment: @Solignis I have just noticed... You are reading the entire file into one variable, aren't you? In that case you have to turn on multiline mode I think (add an 'm' after the second slash of the matching operator, like so: /^guestOSAltName = (.+)$/m).

Answer (score 0):

As @canavanin has said, The problem is that you have a multiline text so you need to use `m//m` in order to have `^` and `$` meaning start and end of line (instead start and end of string). Also is better (safer) to capture the match to a variable (in perl >5.10 also you have named captures as @Potter pointed out). Finally, the m//x is very useful but only if you write your regex in several lines, in order to allow comments and forget about spaces, but in a single line is useless and is error prone because people forget about explicitly write spaces with `\s` or `\s+` and put real (but escaped by the `x`) whitespaces.

Also as you said you wanted to print the line, not only the `'guestOSAltName'`, then you need to capture until the end of line: `m/(^guestOSAltName .+$)/m` (if you add the single-line-mode to the multi-line `//ms` then you would need to make the `.+` non greedy `.+?` to allow `$` to match the end of line before it being consumed by the greedy `.+` in single-line-mode)

```
[not working code]
$vm =~ m/^(\bguestOSAltName\b)/x;
print "$1\n";

[working code]
# make list context with parentheses
(my $guest_os_alias_line) = $vm=~m/^  # start of line (using /m)
                                   (   #start capturing
                                     guestOSAltName
                                     \b  # just in case guestOSAltName is a substring in an unwanted line
                                     .+  # everything else in the line (not matching \n because no /s)
                                   )  # end capturing
                                   $  # end of line (because /m)
                                 /xm; # multiline mode      
print "$guest_os_alias_line\n";
```

If you have more than one of such lines, then you would like to have a multiple-matching-mode /g and capture in an array:

```
(my @guest_os_alias_lines) = $vm=~m/^  # start of line (using /m)
                                   (   #start capturing
                                     guestOSAltName
                                     \b  # just in case guestOSAltName is a substring in an unwanted line
                                     .+  # everything else in the line (not matching \n because no /s)
                                   )  # end capturing
                                   $  # end of line (because /m)
                                 /xmg; # multiline mode (m) and multi-matching(g)      
print "@guest_os_alias_line\n"; # not needed `join ("\n",@guest_os_alias_line)` because the lines contain the `\n` already
```